# How to install apps directly to the external sd card on the samsung galaxy y?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

Everytime while downloading apps from play store an error message occurs saying:"error while downloading insufficient space".what should i do to overcome this type of problem..can anyone help me out.I have already tried by installing "Android SDK" trick but it does'nt be helpfull because..... i think it works on windows 7 and i have windows 8.